# how to put color variables in bash $'...'

Tags: bash, unicode

I have defined in one file which I source from `.bashrc`, color constants.. like these..

> txtgrn='\e[0;32m' # Green
>    txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
>    txtblu='\e[0;34m' # Blue
>    txtpur='\e[0;35m' # Purple

When I try to use them in my $PS1 variable I am getting strange results, in that everything looks fine till I press `CTRL-R` for recursive history search when few characters on the begining scramble, so I am able for example to delete them pressing `CTRL-D` in shell behind that -> pointer :

I am using `$'..'` notation, to be able to insert unicode chars..

```
PS1=$'\xE2\x99\x94 [\\t][\u]->'
```

so now, what is the proper way of inserting variable like `$txtblu` from above, into `PS1` line..?

EDIT:

so line like this one:

```
PS1=$'\n\W\xe2\x98\x85 '$txtpur'\n\n[\t]'$txtrst'[\u]->'
```

makes rendering of symbols and colors ok, but when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type few chars, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> few(2 of them I think) characters appear on the beginning of resulting command search which are not belonging to that history line, and I am able to delete them.

Comment: just to add.. adding colors litterally like \\\[\e[0;31m\\\] works fine..

Comment: like this for example PS1=$'\n\W\xe2\x98\x85 '$txtpur'\n\n[\t]'$txtrst'[\u]->'

Comment: What version of bash do you have (paste the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`)?  You probably need to put `\[` before and `\]` after to tell the shell the color escape sequences don't move the cursor position.

Comment: @Mikel hi Mikel, it's 4.2.45(2)-release.. could you please give me an example on my line from above, how should I wrap that around my color variable? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using non-printing characters in PS1, you need to wrap them in `\[` and `\]`. In your example like this:

```
PS1=$'\n\W\xe2\x98\x85 \['$txtpur'\]\n\n[\t]\['$txtrst'\][\u]->'
```

Explanation: In order to wrap around long commands correctly, bash computes the length of the prompt. However when the PS1 variable contains non-printing characters, the length is computed wrong. Use `\[` and `\]` to indicate "everything between this has a length of 0".

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/nonprintingchars.html

Comment: thanks very much on this explanation, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an extra line in your colors file defining the `STOP`, a way of resetting the colors back to default:

```
txstop='\e[0m' # reset
```

This will be needed to reset the colors after each color change, otherwise everything you type will be colored. Now, the other issue is that bash variables need to be in double quotes or they won't be expanded. Since you're using the `$' '` syntax, this will require some quote acrobatics. For example:

```
PS1=$'\xE2\x99\x94'"$txtblu[\\t]$txstop $txtgrn[\u]$txstop$txtpur->$txstop"
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Comment: well, try now with your line to do CTRL-R to reverse-i-search, type few chars to search for some previous command, and then try CTRL-B, and you will see that your cursor goes past -> and it should not :)

Comment: for reseting color i had var $txtrst just did not mention it in my question, anyway thanks for noticing ;)

Comment: no, it does not, see my comment above, I am getting the same situation as with my own code..

Comment: @branquito strange, it works fine on my system, I can't reproduce your issue.